# PHP login system with RSA algorithm

Tags: php, security, authentication

Currently I am connecting my login system with RSA class (class that is implementation of RSA algorithm in PHP). I've read some info about this algorithm, although I have got some doubts to it and hope that someone can clarify them.

RSA is operating on two keys - public and private, both are generated using algorithm. Are those keys only generated once and then included into site code (one on admin and one on user site)?

The main idea of implementing it is to put on site let say login.php with login form into code a public key and when login and password are sent for verification encrypt them with public key. On server side this message will be decrypted using private key and checked if info are correct and send back true/false info. Can you tell me is it safe and correct use of it?

Comment: Is this login system going to be used on a web site?

Comment: Could you clarify what the design goal is.  Are you implementing some kind of multi system architecture where the initial server to receive the credentials won't be doing the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `HTTPS` instead of getting lost in the implementation of these algorithms. I bet a Javascript implementation would signify a large overhead on client-side. When you want to encrypt your pockets, let the Transport Layer or the Application Layer (HTTPS) to do it - it's tested, it's fast, it's working, it takes a few minutes to setup.

Comment: I wouldn't say it takes a few minutes to setup, but this is the best route by far.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't implement this - use HTTPS instead. What you proposed is not secure at all. The form data will not be secure if you encrypt it on the client side using JavaScript. JavaScript is not good for encryption.

The basic rule is anything executing on the client is malicious. To run an encryption on the client is a really bad idea.

Again - use HTTPS or don't do it.

Comment: so, if I am using POST method to send login and password to server to connect to db and stuff like this the https is the safest way? Also, if I am getting info from db (SELECT...) and db is on my server I don't have to bother about security there or is there also a way to protect it?

Comment: It's not malicious. You hack the public key the way you want, if you have it. The private key holder does not interested in it. It's just not effective - bold move.

Comment: @sebap123: HTTPS just encrypts the traffic, you still have to use due diligence to properly escape all strings you use to enter/query into the database.

Comment: @Dyin: It is malicious if an attacker can disable/modify it. He can attack it with XSS, browser exploits, etc. If you truly care about security, then you must assume anything that the client has access to should be treated like Uranium.

Comment: Ok, so now I understand - use HTTPS and let those algorithms take care of everything (excluding string escape or something like that). Thank you.

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik: It's trivial, that you will validate the data after decryption, that's not what I was talking about. It's the client's responsibility usually to keep his/her traffic and system safe, not ours. We just give a protocol, to encrypt his/her data. If the client entity gets attacked, it does not matter if the pockets are encrypted or not.

Comment: @Dyin: If it doesn't matter, then why use encryption in the first place. Sounds wasteful.

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik: Hm. If the client entity receives a successful attack, then every pockets are in the hands of the attacker before it even gets encrypted. If the attacker would have the public key from the client, chances are, that he/she can encrypt data with it. ;) That's all. The posted protocol of RSA idea would be fine as HTTPS. It's just not effective!

Comment: @Dyin: "That is all". That's a dangerous thing to say. Never underestimate the capability of an attacker to use every bit of knowledge. That said, I think we can agree that it's the client's job to keep his network secure. Btw, the posted Protocol is not how HTTPS works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the transmission to be secure you can't use a server-side scripting language for it. The encryption and decryption will first occur when the cleartext password has reached the server, giving an listener good time to intercept. You could use a javascript implementation of RSA to encrypt the password client-side and then php on the server-side to decrypt it.

You would have your public key for encrypting and the private key on the server for decrypting.

Comment: OK, thank you for info. However, it doesn't say one thing - those keys should be in code or where, because using javascript makes this code very visible.

Comment: If the goal here is secure transmission from client to server then SSL is the correct way to go.

Comment: Yes, the public key is public. Everybody is allowed to see it, which make RSA so nice. The private key is supposed to be kept hidden for yourself (or the server in this case)